# Grid System Order in Boostrap 2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the [Grid System](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) of Bootstrap 2.

I want to make a header with some text, and an image on the right of it.
Therefore I made a `row`, and put a `span8` and a `span4` inside of it.

However, when the window gets too small for the content to be displayed side by side, I want the `span4` div to come before the `span8` div.

```
<div class="hero-unit">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span8">
                This is some text
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <img src="image.png" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

How can I do this?
So in other words, how can I change the order of the `div`s.

If I'm not completely mistaking, there is no such thing described in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with media queries and floats.

Should look somewhat like this:

```
<div class="span4 pull-right"><!-- Image here --></div>
<div class="span8"><!-- Text here --></div>
```

Now you should use a media query (as seen in the responsive.less file) to switch when the screen size jumps below a specific mark. Then you make sure that the `span4`'s float is removed. You might need to use `.row-fluid` instead of the usual `.row` and use your own padding to make it look great.